# Flutter how to make custom tab indicator like this?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I was trying to make it with `CustomPaint` but image shadow not working

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this parameter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTabIndicator extends Decoration {
  final double radius;

  final Color color;


  final double indicatorHeight;

  const CustomTabIndicator({
    this.radius = 8,
    this.indicatorHeight = 4,
    this.color = Colors.red,
  });

  @override
  _CustomPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) {
    return _CustomPainter(
      this,
      onChanged,
      radius,
      color,
      indicatorHeight,
    );
  }
}

class _CustomPainter extends BoxPainter {
  final CustomTabIndicator decoration;
  final double radius;
  final Color color;
  final double indicatorHeight;

  _CustomPainter(
      this.decoration,
      VoidCallback? onChanged,
      this.radius,
      this.color,
      this.indicatorHeight,
      ) : super(onChanged);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    assert(configuration.size != null);

    final Paint paint = Paint();
    double xAxisPos = offset.dx + configuration.size!.width / 2;
    double yAxisPos = offset.dy + configuration.size!.height - indicatorHeight/2;
    paint.color = color;

    RRect fullRect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset(xAxisPos, yAxisPos),
        width: configuration.size!.width / 3,
        height: indicatorHeight,
      ),
      topLeft: Radius.circular(radius),
      topRight: Radius.circular(radius),
    );

    canvas.drawRRect(fullRect, paint);
  }
}
```

**use : indicator: CustomTabIndicator(),**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for tab

```
Tab(
    child: CustomPaint(
        size: Size(50, 5),
        painter: CurvePainter(),
      ),
   ),
```

For line with sharp ends.

```
class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.black;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill; 

    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2, size.width, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, 0, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```